# which folder to select run a website on IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, browser, iis-7.5

I am not getting which folder I should select for physical path selection while creating a new website in browser

Comment: Wrong place to ask your question

Comment: where can I search for this. Sir I have a folder having the physical path. But what are all things should be there in IIS while creating new website. @nrathaus

Comment: Usually IIS expects the files to present under `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give your own the physical path to your IIS website

it may be

%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot    -> Default path

Or you can specify your own directory based on your requirement.

The physical path contains some information related to iis configuration.